# java development and redeployment

Tags: java, spring, playframework

I used playframework previously. Development with play! is so fast. It has an internal java compiler and all the actlon methods are static. So the result is awesome.
Nowadays i use spring on netbeans. Netbeans has a deploy on save feature. But redeployment time is greater than 10 seconds. I used jrebel. But jrebel does not give the same effect. I used eclipse. Eclipse is worst than netbeans. Why java development should be so difficult? Is there any method for fast redeployment?

Comment: I wish my redeployment time was 10 seconds.

Comment: I want a pony. And some liquorice.

Comment: Get back to Play! or use Grails....

Comment: "But jrebel does not give the same effect." - could you clarify that. What kind of effect do you miss? JRebel can do hotswap for you and also supports Spring configuration changes. Anything else you would like to see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already mentioned JRebel. There are other options, but they are not faster. For example, WTP plugin for Eclipse. You can use jetty-maven plugin, you can use emended jetty-server for development. You can use file-sync plugin for Eclipse. This is 3 most popular and fastest way to deploy project. But all of them require redeploy of server.

You will never get this speed like Play framework or some dynamic compiler language. But probably it's not necessary ?

If you change static resources, like jsp, js, css, you don't need deploy. If you change Java code, just test your code with JUnit or something else. Or write a bunch of code and make deploy

IMHO the more experience you gain, rarely you make deploy =) You don't need to check, what's going on, because you know exactly, what you are doing =)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why Play deployment is so fast, is that it isn't an actual deployment in the original sense of the word. Play checks for the modifications in your Java code, then takes just that file and compiles it and changes the state of the JVM to incorporate the new class.

A real deployment to an application server or event to "just" a servlet container is more than that. The package (war, ear) has to be expanded. Internal structures of the app server has to be updated and the app has to be started. This all takes time because much more components are working together.